# Rails validation message error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do something like this:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :message => custom_message

def custom_message
  "Custom Message"
end
```

But when I try it I get "undefined local variable or method for custom method"

Whats up with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I figured it out. If you use a symbol instead of the method directly.

e.g :message => :custom_message

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this:

```
def self.custom_message
  "Custom Message"
end

validates_presence_of :name, message: custom_message
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,, if im not wrong

before_save :custom_message
def custom_message
self.custom_message = "Custom Message" if published == true
end
end

Comment: hmmm not sure why I would want to do that... 
just wanna know why the validates method doesnt't see the local method

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the definition of custom_message before the validates_presence_of line? validates_presence_of is a class method, and when it is evaluated Ruby has not yet seen the definition below it.